# I am doing animation frame by frame and it doesn't work for some reason, JS

Tags: javascript, animation

The issue is simple, animation doesn't work for some reason,
[got a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yty86jEu4nagdRb0JeiFQMX2rSWbYupZ/view?usp=drive_link) here is an `onload` function

```js
let frames;

let dino = {
    animation : [
        startRunImg,
        secondRunImg,
        thirdRunImg,
        startRunImg
    ],
    x : dinoX,
    y : dinoY,
    w : dinoWidth,
    h : dinoHeight,
    onGround : true,
    frame : 0
}

window.onload = function() {
    board = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    scoreElemnt = document.querySelector('#score');
    bestScoreElement = document.querySelector('#bestScore');
    boardWidth = board.width;
    boardHeight = board.height;
    context = board.getContext('2d');

    setInterval(placePipes, 1500);
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // requestAnimationFrame
};
```

Here is my `update`

```js
function update(){
    requestAnimationFrame(update); //requestAnimationFrame
    frames++;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, board.width, board.height);


    drawBase();
    drawDino();
    drawPipes();

    if(state.current == state.game){
        velocityY += gravity;
        dino.y = Math.max(dino.y + velocityY, 0);
        colisionDetection();
        updateScore();
    }
};
```

`drawDino` function

```js
function drawDino(){
    let dinoA = dino.animation[dino.frame];
    context.drawImage(dinoA, dino.x, dino.y, dino.w, dino.h);

    if(state.current == state.game){
        dino.period = 5;
        if(frames == 0){
            dino.frame = (dino.frame + 1) % dino.animation.length;
        }
    };
};
```

i checked my files and they are all correct.
Also no errors messages in console
(if i provided not enough information, note in comments)

Comment: the rest of the code `drawBase()`, `drawPipes()`, etc would be helpful, also what doesn't work? Is there a javascript error in the console? Is the animation scuffed? The error message or a video of the animation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `update()` from `requestAnimationFrame(() => { ... update() })`

Comment: u mean in `onload` function? i did so, and the issue still remains

Comment: No get update to call itself

Comment: Does it draw anything?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.
To `let frames;` needed to add `0`, so `let frames = 0;`